# Export java web service from eclipse java ee

Tags: java, iphone, web-services, export

This might be a newbie question. But I am working with iPhone programming and I have hosted my own webservices written in Java on a ubuntu linux and Eclipse EE edition with a glashfish server. Is there any easy way to export this webservice and getting it hosted elsewhere.

I have been looking around for a solution but have not found the grail yet.

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you have in mind when you think "export", but you're deploying a WAR file locally on Glassfish.  That's the package you need to pick up and move to your hosting service.  They, in turn, have to accept WAR files and deploy on a Java EE app server.

Your WAR file should be portable if it has everything your app needs.  Make clear what you need from the server (e.g. dependent JARs); everything else should be in your WAR.

Comment: It is exacltly what i mean, thank you, i will take a look into this

Answer (score 2):

If you can adapt your solution to the limitations of the Google Application Engine, they will host it for free.

This strongly depends on how many Java EE features you use.

Comment: Actually i am looking into using the google app engine to host a webservice. It is basically retrieve and adding stuff to a database.

Answer (score 1):

> there any easy way to export this webservice and getting it hosted elsewhere.

You just need to take war file and deploy it somewhere else you want